# How to route FORWARDed packets differently from local traffic

Tags: iptables, route

I have a gateway box with two internet connections, eth0 and eth1, and a LAN connection eth2.

Currently eth1 is unused and eth2 LAN traffic is forwarded/masqueraded and sent to the internet via eth0.

What is the most straightforward way to send the eth2 LAN traffic to the internet via eth1?  I want local traffic to still go via eth0.

(I am aware that I can tag packets in iptables, then route on the tag, but I was wondering whether I had missed a simpler solution.)

Answer (score 1):

set the gateway for the local network to the interface eth1 and for localhost to eth0 in the routing table in your box.

Comment: Could you give an example?  I thought a box could only have one default gateway, unless you use multiple routing tables and packet marking.